# how to build a joomla component administrator pages

Tags: joomla

Now I am building a joomla component administrator pages of joomla 3.2.

What are the files and functions of the files?
How could I put a menu, a sidebar, a filter in the viewing page like a back end layout is from joomla 3.2 contact component.

[image]

And as a sample, the administrator component file of com_contact has following files, what are the functions of them?

```
access.xml
config.xml
contact.php  -- already understand
contact.xml
controller.php  -- already understand 
controllers   -- already understand
helpers
index.html   -- already understand 
models  -- already understand
sql  -- already understand
tables  -- already understand
views  -- already understand
```

Comment: Have you read this carefully ?


 http://docs.joomla.org/Portal:Component_Development

Comment: Hey, After i add in those tool bar icons, how should i add in clicking effect, i.e. when clicking on the icons, there is respect effect?

Comment: You have write javascript for this. Refer this http://docs.joomla.org/J1.5:How_to_create_a_custom_button and you will find a javascript code in this which will helps you.

Comment: I mean, for example, clicking on NEW, the page lead to add new view page.

Comment: When javascript works for you, you have to write code on controller of your component which will detect the option,view and task and then send control to a proper controller and view then view will displays a proper template.

Comment: JToolbarHelper::publish('contacts.publish', 'JTOOLBAR_PUBLISH', true);    what is this contacts.publish?

Comment: If you see the function body of publish you will get the arguments like (task, alt, check). So, contacts.publish is task and 'JTOOLBAR_PUBLISH' is alt and true is the value of check parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read the documentation on [Joomla Component Development](http://docs.joomla.org/Portal%3aComponent_Development) and also check out this site which creates the files needed to start off a component and saves a lot of time:

[Joomla Component Creator](http://www.component-creator.com/en/)